# python code for getting multiple Url's and scanning the url's one after other

Tags: security, url

Hi i am new to Python coding . I need a code for getting multiple URL's and need to Scan one by one.

For eg: If i have the following URL's https://www.example.com;https://www.site1.com;https://www.site2.com;https://www.site3.com;https://www.ghui.com

I need to get this URL's and initate the scans one by one in my tool (HP WebInspect)

Comment: Please show your work so far http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have googled it but i didn't get any idea on how to get multiple urls in python